# Free desktop photo organizer/manager

Tags: gratis, photography, cloud-storage, collection-manager, facial-recognition

I need an app that does the things below:

1. Allow me to organize my photos with smart features like facial recognition.

   (Adobe Bridges: no; Google Photos: yes)
2. See my gallery on Android devices via cloud.

   (Adobe Bridges: no; Google Photos: yes)
3. Cloud Sync editions (preferentially with Dropbox): photos edited on desktop automatically sync to the cloud. (Since I can't have my photos on a folder at my desktop, I can edit them at my desktop and automatically sync.)

   (Adobe Bridges: no; Google Photos: no)